# using select statement to set a Resultset into a single cell in sql

Tags: java, sqlite

I'm trying to set a value from a `Resultset` into a single cell in another column....
the table is something like this

```
idnumber     courseCode   remarks       semester
12/073.      CPE302.      Fail.         2
12/073.      CPE304.      Pass.         1
12/074.      CPE302.      Pass.         2
12/073.      EEE401.      Fail.         1
12/074.      CPE304.      Pass.         1
```

...what I want to do is select the courseCode  where `idnumber=12/073` and `remarks=Fail`,using the result I want to update another table `cgpa`, a single Cell in `cgpa` that has a column name remarks with the `Resultset`.

Here is what I tried:

```
try {
    String value=isearch.getText();
    String value1="Fail";
    String sql=" select courseCode from ResultUpload where idnumber='" + value + "' and remarks='" + value1 + "' ";
    pst.conn.preparedStatement(sql);
    pst.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next()){
        String course = rs.getString("courseCode");
        String sql1="update cgpa set remarks='" + course + "' where idnumber='" + value + "' ";
        pst.conn.preparedStatement(sql);
        pst.execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: thankz Ullas for the edit

Comment: I would suggest you read: http://bobby-tables.com/, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html and do the update in one statement, something like: `update cgpa set remarks=(select courseCode from ResultUpload where idnumber=? AND remarks = ?) where idnumber=?`

Comment: thanks @RC it works,the problem is i want it to pick all the values,but now is only picking the first value in the column and inserting into the remarks column... is there any where i can make it to pick all the values and set it to the single cell with spacing or coma in between them

Comment: then fetch the values, build the comma separated "update value" (`StringBuilder` is your friend) and perform the update

Comment: ok...i have look onto it,but is the first time i am using it with sql ...can you please give me a hint or an example so that i can make it work. once again thanks@RC it was really helpful